# Login in SQL Server with different windows user account

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am having issues logging into a SQL Server database using a different windows user cred...

This is my code:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;UID=DOMAIN\DiffUser;PWD=password;Integrated Security=True;" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery  
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection  
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd   
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
$SQLConnection.Close()
```

However, I get this error when I run it:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\CurrentUser'."

It seems like the code is not using the connection string I supplied and is trying to log in as myself?

I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly...

If I remove `Integrated Security=True;` from the connection string, I get the expected error

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\DiffUser'."

I'm fairly confused to what is happening here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated security will use the current context. It's not something you can set in the connection string. If you need to use a context other than the current context, you will need to impersonate that context before opening the connection.

Perhaps WindowsIdentity.Impersonate might be of use. You will normally need the credentials.  (Impersonation without credentials is very dangerous.)

If you want to impersonate with SSMS for testing, shift right-click SSMS will show an option for Run as different user.  After logging in as the required user, SSMS will be running as that user.